# How to keep timer(winforms timer) in a continuos loop

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

Ok, so my problem is as follows, I have a timer that draws a frame every 2 seconds (testing purposes) when I press D (by press I mean the D key is continuously held down), anyways when I first press D, the form will wait 2 seconds then draws the images as it should, but the problem is it does this only once. Hence after the 2 seconds,the remanding frames will be drawn at the fastest speed in which the form can draw it at. So, how do I make sure the frame will be drawn only every 2 seconds continuously, while keeping the interval of 2 seconds no matter how long I press the D key... here is my code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form 
{
    Keys moveRight;
    Keys moveLeft;

    public static bool isMovingR = false;
    public static bool isMovingL = false;
    public static bool canMoveR = false;

    Bitmap stnd = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.Standing);
    static Bitmap wlk_1_RL = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.Walk_1_RL);
    static Bitmap wlk_3_RL = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.Walk_3_RL);
    static Bitmap wlk_4_LL = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.Walk_4_LL);
    static Bitmap wlk_6_LL = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.Walk_6_LL);

    Animation animate = new Animation(new Bitmap[] { wlk_1_RL, wlk_3_RL,
        wlk_4_LL, wlk_6_LL });


    Timer timer = new Timer();

    int imageX = 5;
    int imageY = 234;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isMovingR == false)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(stnd, imageX, imageY);
            //Refresh();
        }
        if (canMoveR == true)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(animate.Frame2Draw(), imageX, imageY);
            timer.Stop();// this simply stops the animation from continuing once I have stopped press D
        }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        moveRight = Keys.D;
        moveLeft = Keys.A;

        if (e.KeyCode == moveRight)
        {
            isMovingR = true;
            timer.Enabled = true;
            timer.Interval = 2000;                
            timer.Tick += Timer1_Tick;
            //imageX += 5;
            Refresh();
        } else if (e.KeyCode == moveLeft)
        {
            isMovingL = true;
            imageX -= 5;
            Refresh();
        } 

    }

    private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D)
        {
            isMovingR = false;
            canMoveR = false;
            Animation.slctdImg = 0;
            this.Refresh();
        }
    }

    private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        canMoveR = true;
        this.Invalidate(); // calls the OnPaint event
        timer.Stop(); // testing purposes and also to let you know timer.stop() doesn't really fix my problem in this case
    }
}
```

}

UPDATED CODE, based on Kirak solution

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer.Enabled = true;
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Tick += Timer1_Tick;
    }


    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (canMoveR == true)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(animate.Frame2Draw(), imageX, imageY);
            timer.Stop();
        }


    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        moveRight = Keys.D;
        moveLeft = Keys.A;

        if (e.KeyCode == moveRight)
        {
            isMovingR = true;
            //imageX += 5;
            Refresh();
        } else if (e.KeyCode == moveLeft)
        {
            isMovingL = true;
            imageX -= 5;
            Refresh();
        } 

    }

    private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D)
        {
            isMovingR = false;
            canMoveR = false;
            Animation.slctdImg = 0;
            this.Refresh();
        }
    }

    private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (isMovingR == true)
        {
            canMoveR = true;
            this.Invalidate(); // calls the OnPaint event, hence all things that the OnPaint 
//event draws, will be redrawn, you make ask your self why i would need 
//the canMoveR to be set to true then, this is because i plan on adding more things
// so for future purpose, all things to be drawn in the game will
// will only be drawn when i want them to be drawn or under specific circumstances
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: remove event Timer1_Tick on finished or add only one time

Comment: what do you mean by add only 1 time

Comment: Each time this command is processed: timer.Tick + = Timer1_Tick ;, the event is added again causing the tick to be executed as many times as the event has been added.

Comment: Your approach does not look correct.  The Tick event handler can implement your game logic, moving objects around.  That requires the timer to tick at 15 or 31 msec and only stop when the user pauses the game.

Comment: @RovannLinhalis o i see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set the timer on button press - have a timer ticking every 2 seconds that checks if the button is pressed and takes action if it is.
eg (pseudocode):

```
public Form1()
{
    timer.Enabled = true;
    timer.Interval = 2000;
}

KeyCode keyPressed;

private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    keyPressed = e.KeyCode;
}

private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (keyPressed == Keys.D)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Update to address new code:
If you want to unset the "canMoveR" you may want to set a timeout variable - something like this:

```
int timeout = 0;
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    keyPressed = e.KeyCode;
    timeout = 2; // 2 seconds assuming your timer ticks every 1000ms
}
```

then on timer tick:

```
private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    --timeout; //will go down to 1 the first tick, then down to 0 on the second
    if (timeout == 0)
    {
        canMoveR = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: so i created in the Timer1_tick event  and if statement, that detects if the bool variable "isMovingR" is set to true, the "isMovingR" variable will be set to true when i press D. Now when ismovingR is set to true, the timer_tick event if statement detects that make the variable "canMoveR" equal to true, then in the OnPaint there is an if statement that detects if the "canMoveR" variable is true, if it is it draws the frames accordingly, but how do i disable the "canMoveR" after the 2 seconds have passed, i will pose and update code

Answer (score 0):

Every time press D, the event Timer1_Tick is added, so, on second time press D, the event run 2 times. Set event on constructor.

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
            timer.Enabled = false;
            timer.Interval = 2000;                
            timer.Tick += Timer1_Tick;

    }


    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isMovingR == false)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(stnd, imageX, imageY);
            //Refresh();
        }
        if (canMoveR == true)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(animate.Frame2Draw(), imageX, imageY);
            timer.Stop();// this simply stops the animation from continuing once I have stopped press D
        }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        moveRight = Keys.D;
        moveLeft = Keys.A;

        if (e.KeyCode == moveRight)
        {
            isMovingR = true;
            //imageX += 5;
   timer.Enabled = true;
            Refresh();
        } else if (e.KeyCode == moveLeft)
        {
            isMovingL = true;
            imageX -= 5;
            Refresh();
        } 

    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but your solution doesn't work perhaps you made a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood your problem. Sorry. You can do as kirlac said.

Comment: No worries m8, you were still of help, I now know 1 more way on how to not solve my problem